# Mapping an element with API information in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, themoviedb-api

I am developing a react app with a movie API (https://developers.themoviedb.org). The thing is that i am trying to put information from the API in a card. I use `useState` and `useEffect` for this. Also, I use Axios to bring it from the API. I don't know, I can't see what is not working. The error message is map is not a function but also, I believe that is something wrong in my `useEffect`. Please help!

```
const Home = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=**APIKEY**")
      .then(res => {
        setMovies(res.data);

      }).catch(console.log)
  },
    []
  );


  return (
    <section id="main-page">
      <div className='list-main-page'>
        <a href='#'>
          <h2>
            Películas que son tendencia
            <FontAwesomeIcon className='arrow-list' icon={faArrowRight} />
          </h2>
        </a>
        <div className='card-list-container'>

        {movies.map((movie, i) => {
            return (
              <Card key={i} image={movie.poster_path} />
            )})
          }

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: You leaked you TMDb API key, make sure you reset it.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the values of response are inside `res.data.results`. So you just need to change:

```
setMovies(res.data);
```

to:

```
setMovies(res.data.results);
```

If you are using a **typescript** project, would also be good to you map the properties that you want from api with an interface:

```
// just an examples of some properties
interface MoviesProps {
  id: number;
  video: boolean;
  vote_count: number;
  title: string;
}
```

and set your state as:

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState<MoviesProps[]>([]);
```

Comment: Note that the interface is only possible in Typescript. Javascript does not support interfaces or types natively.

Comment: Hi @prohit, i will update it with the info. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be used like this code:

```
setMovies(res.data.results);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not post your api key publicly like that.

You should make yourself comfortable with the form that is returned from the public API.

```
{
   "page": 1,
   "results": [...],
   "total_pages": 1000,
   "total_results": 20000
}
```

Here we see the result of our `res.data`. We can use it like a Javascript object since Axios converts this JSON for us. (You could also convert it yourself with JSON.parse() )

The actual `movies` you were looking for are encapsulated inside the `result` array in the data. In your attempt, you were trying to `map` (which is a function from arrays) the result object, which obviously is not an array, hence the error you are facing.

To fix this, you would have to save the `result` in your state

```js
setMovies(res.data.results);
```

Answer (score 0):

data from the api comes as an object `{"page":1, "results":[...]}` so to set movie's array in your state you should access the results array as follows;

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=API_KEY")
      .then(res => {
        setMovies(res.data.results);

      }).catch(error  => 
         console.log(error)
      )
  },
    []
  );
```

Avoid posting your API keys

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the `setMovies` hook. You need to change it from `setMovies(res.data);` to `setMovies(res.data.results` as that is the hook that will receive the data from the API.